# Sorting Array from a MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE level = 7 ");
```

After querying the database, I have a list of level 7 users (installers). I use a while() loop to display all the installers. Each installer has a post code which, using PHP and GoogleMaps, is compared against the postcode of the currently logged in customer and returns the distance between the two post codes.

How can I sort this list of installers by the newly created "distance" variable?

Comment: Required output and table schema must have been shared to get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

```
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $volume[$key]  = $row['volume'];
    $edition[$key] = $row['edition'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC, $edition, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

Is the example your looking for. You only have 1 key though

```
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $var[$key]  = $row['your_new_var'];

}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($var, SORT_DESC, $data);
?>
```

Where `your_new_var` is the key sorting on